# Is there a nice way to use `->` directly as a function in Idris?

Tags: dependent-type, idris

One can return a type in a function in Idris, for example

```
t : Type -> Type -> Type
t a b = a -> b
```

But the situation came up (when experimenting with writing some parsers) that I wanted to use `->` to fold a list of types, ie

```
typeFold : List Type -> Type
typeFold = foldr1 (->)
```

So that `typeFold [String, Int]` would give `String -> Int : Type`. This doesn't compile though:

```
error: no implicit arguments allowed
    here, expected: ")",
    dependent type signature,
    expression, name
typeFold = foldr1 (->)
                   ^
```

But this works fine:

```
t : Type -> Type -> Type
t a b = a -> b

typeFold : List Type -> Type
typeFold = foldr1 t
```

Is there a better way to work with `->`, and if not is it worth raising as a feature request?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with using `->` in this way is that it's not a type constructor but a binder, where the name bound for the domain is in scope in the range, so `->` itself doesn't have a type directly. Your definition of `t` for example wouldn't capture a dependent type like `(x : Nat) -> P x`.

While it is a bit fiddly, what you're doing is the right way to do this. I'm not convinced we should make special syntax for `(->)` as a type constructor - partly because it really isn't one, and partly because it feels like it would lead to more confusion when it doesn't work with dependent types.

Comment: "where the name bound for the domain is in scope in the range" I can't parse this properly, can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The `Data.Morphisms` module provides something like this, except you have to do all the wrapping/unwrapping around the `Morphism` "newtype".

Comment: Then one could use something like `typeFold = foldr1 (~>)`