# Why doesn't (*3) `map` (+100) work in Idris?

Tags: haskell, idris

In Haskell, functions are functors and the following code works as expected:

```
(*3) `fmap` (+100) $ 1
```

The output is 303 of course. However, in Idris (with fmap -> map), it gives the following error:

> Can't find implementation for `Functor (\uv => Integer -> uv)`

To me this seems like functions aren't implemented as functors in Idris, at least not like they are in Haskell, but why is that?

Furthermore, what exactly does the type signature `(\uv => Integer -> uv)` mean? It *looks* like some partially applied function, and that's  what would be expected from a functor implementation, but the syntax is a bit confusing, specifically what `\` which is supposed to be used for a lambda/literal is doing there.

Comment: I'm not an Idris expert, but it should be the eta-expanded version of `(->) Integer`. Here, `(->)` is partially applied, but in `\uv => (->) Integer uv` it is fully applied. Both are eta-convertible.

Comment: @chi ah right that makes sense. thanks. I think it confused me because I don't interpret types as first-order intuitively yet

Comment: Is it due to Idris functions being total? I don't know Idris well enough to come up with a good example, but it seems like the composition of two total functions is not, itself, guaranteed to be total. (My first try was something like `(10.0 /) . (10.0 - )`, although that function applied to 10 evaluates to `Infinity`.)

Comment: @chepner I could be wrong but I don't think Idris is a total language. It's turing-complete, and for example isn't `10.0 /` not total itself?

Comment: Well, `(10.0 /)` *is* total, since it maps `10.0` to `Infinity`. `(.)` is marked as total, but my glancing familiarity with Idris makes it difficult for me to come up with a good example of a partial function.

Comment: @chepner oh! I tried it with `log (-1)` but that turns out to be NaN. cheating!:p

Comment: I thought maybe I could do something with `Prelude.Nat.(-)`, but it uses dependent typing to make that total as well.

Comment: Oh, it looks likes it's just a matter of syntax, not semantics: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/idris-lang/f7iSKzKBF1A. TL;DR `(->)` isn't a type constructor.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32043985/2747511) is related.

Comment: @chepner The composition of two total functions is total, if it is well-typed at all.

Comment: FWIW, I sometimes think we would be better off in Haskell without `Functor (->)` too. Shorthands involving this instance are often confusing and would be better expressed with `Arrow` combinators, whereas for serious larger-scale uses of the `Monad` instance it's better to use the more explicit `Reader` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functor is an interface.  In Idris, implementations are restricted to data or type constructors, i.e. defined using the `data` keyword.  I am not an expert in dependent types, but I believe this restriction is required—practically, at least—for a sound interface system.

When you ask for the type of  `\a => Integer -> a` at the REPL, you get

```
\a => Integer -> a : Type -> Type
```

In Haskell we would consider this to be a real type constructor, one that can be made into an instance of type classes such as `Functor`.  In Idris however, `(->)` is not a type constructor but a [binder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27271810/4878871).

The closest thing to your example in Idris would be

```
((*3) `map` Mor (+100)) `applyMor` 1
```

using the [Data.Morphisms](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/base/Data/Morphisms.idr) module.  Or step by step:

```
import Data.Morphisms

f : Morphism Integer Integer
f = Mor (+100)

g : Morphism Integer Integer
g = (*3) `map` f

result : Integer
result = g `applyMor` 1
```

This works because `Morphism` is a real type constructor, with a `Functor` implementation defined in the library.

Comment: There is also infix syntax `(~>)` for `Morphism`, so you can write `Integer ~> Integer`